# netbeans doesn't display properly after permission change

Tags: permissions, netbeans

So basically i installed netbeans 7.2 through the site and everything worked fine. I then changed permissions for /var/www so that my apache2 could write on it without problems.
After that netbeans started behaving strangely and giving errors and the fonts where all ugly. So i re-installed it but the problem continued. I have options in Tools that don't even show up anymore. 
If i open with Sudo the fonts come up nicely again, but the amount of options still isn't the same as the original installation
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found a "solution". After the new installation i have to sudo ./netbeans inside the netbeans bin folder. After that i will have menu items missing. I have to re-enable the  plugins so that everything starts working again (usually they come enabled)